# image gallery display with a main image and smaller images

Tags: html, css

I have an image gallery but can't really display it the way I want. I'd like to have a main image which is bigger and display the rest on the right side of the main image, under each other.
The code:

```
<div class="gallery">
<a href="images/1.jpg">
<img class="card-img-top" src="images/1.jpg" alt="Fő kép" style="width: 50%;">

<div class="image-container">
<img src="images/1.jpg" alt="Egy kép a hirdetésről">
<img src="images/motor.jpg" alt="Egy kép a hirdetésről">
<img src="images/motor2.jpg" alt="Egy kép a hirdetésről">
<img src="images/2.jpg" alt="Egy kép a hirdetésről">
</div>
</a>

<a href="images/motor.jpg"></a>
<a href="images/motor2.jpg"></a>
<a href="images/2.jpg"></a>
<a href="images/1.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

```
.image-container {
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.image-container img {
    max-width: 20vh;
}
```

This is how it looks like atm:
[image]

and this is the one it should look like:
[image: image2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.gallery {width: 100%;}
.gallery a {
display: flex;
}
.gallery img{width: 80%; height: auto;}
.image-container {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
margin-left: 11px;
width: 20%;
height: 300px;
overflow: scroll;
}

.image-container img {
margin: 11px 0 0;}
.image-container img:first-child {
margin: 0 0 0;}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
<a href="https://images.pexels.com/photos/417074/pexels-photo-417074.jpeg">
<img class="card-img-top" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/417074/pexels-photo-417074.jpeg" alt="Fő kép">

<div class="image-container">
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/417074/pexels-photo-417074.jpeg" alt="Egy kép a hirdetésről">
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/417074/pexels-photo-417074.jpeg" alt="Egy kép a hirdetésről">
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/417074/pexels-photo-417074.jpeg" alt="Egy kép a hirdetésről">
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/417074/pexels-photo-417074.jpeg" alt="Egy kép a hirdetésről">
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/417074/pexels-photo-417074.jpeg" alt="Egy kép a hirdetésről">
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/417074/pexels-photo-417074.jpeg" alt="Egy kép a hirdetésről">
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/417074/pexels-photo-417074.jpeg" alt="Egy kép a hirdetésről">
</div>
</a>

<a href="https://images.pexels.com/photos/417074/pexels-photo-417074.jpeg"></a>
<a href="https://images.pexels.com/photos/417074/pexels-photo-417074.jpeg"></a>
<a href="https://images.pexels.com/photos/417074/pexels-photo-417074.jpeg"></a>
<a href="https://images.pexels.com/photos/417074/pexels-photo-417074.jpeg"></a>
</div>
```

I have used flex css to implement your design.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The only problem is that it destroys the resolution of the main image. https://i.postimg.cc/PqJrLJMs/image.png Is it possible to set the small images scrollable so the main image can be the original resoultion?